# Assign multiple values to a parameter in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have added a parameter to my report with the option "Allow Multiple Values" checked.

This is a status column (IE, Proposed, In Progress, Completed, Canceled), and I want the user to be able to select which (and how many) different OrderStatus to report on.

How I normally set parameters is:

```
report.SetParameterValue("@dtBegin", dtBegin.DateTime);
```

What I tried to do for the multiple values was something like this:

```
//pseudo loop
foreach(int intOrderStatus in intSelectedOrderStatuses)
{
    report.Parameter_OrderStatus.CurrentValues.AddValue(intOrderStatus);
}
```

I have checked it does add the values to the OrderStatus parameter, but when the report runs, the CrystalReports dialog pops up and asks me to enter values for the OrderStatus parameter. So it seems as though the values aren't "commited" to the parameter. I have done a number of searches and can't figure out why it's not working.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if my answer makes sense. Are you adding value for the 
*SAME* parameter (using code), for which CR is prompting you?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I cannot see your answer. In response to your question, I am assigning values to the parameter OrderStatus, and when the report is run, a prompt appears asking for data for the OrderStatus parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the parameter value with an array of ints.

```
report.SetParameterValue("@OrderStatus", new int[]{1,2,3});
```

in the select expert you would use the *in* operator.

```
{table.order_status_id} in {?@OrderStatus}
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that you could pass in an array of ints like this. Haven't tried it, but I'll assume that it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, make a normal parameter field,i.e without multiple values, only discreet values true, all you need to pass is 1,2,3,4. "," is the delimiter for separation use what ever you think works for you, then in record selection formula simply put

```
{table.order_status_id} in split({@OrderStatus}, ",")
```

all you need to pass from you page is the string 1,2,3,4 and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the parameter to Hidden in the Crystal Reports parameter options?

Comment: No I haven't. Where do I set this option? Also why would the Hidden option resolve my issue?

Comment: Bah. Please disregard this answer. I was thinking about Reporting Services reports, not Crystal. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think that you should be able to add intOrderStatus to either a ParameterDiscreteValue or ParameterRangeValue and pass that into Parameter_OrderStatus.CurrentValues instead of intOrderStatus.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have same issue. The work around is very simple. Don't add data source after parameters. e.g

```
report.SetParameterValue("@dtBegin", dtBegin.DateTime);
report.SetParameterValue("@dtBegin2", dtBegin.DateTime1);
//Note datasource is assigned after parameters
report.SetDatasource(dataset);
```

The crystal report will refresh parameters before applying data source to report. 
The below is the not popup discrete dialog box

```
//Note Datasource is applied before parameters
report.SetDatasource(dataset);
report.SetParameterValue("@dtBegin", dtBegin.DateTime);
report.SetParameterValue("@dtBegin2", dtBegin.DateTime1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is tested in *Crystal Reports* version *13.0.20*:

**1)** In `Parameter Fields` section add new parameter as follow:

```
Name: ParamMultipleOrderStatus
Type: Number
Value Options: 
    Allow multiple values: true
```

**2)** Choose the `Select Expert Record ...` in Crystal Reports and code may like this (use `=` operator):

```
{Orders.OrderStatus} = {?ParamMultipleOrderStatus}
```

**3)** Use following code:

```
foreach (int intOrderStatus in intSelectedOrderStatuses)
{
    report.ParameterFields["ParamMultipleOrderStatus"].CurrentValues.AddValue(intOrderStatus);
}
```