# How to pass multiple integer parameter into crystal reports using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

im writing c# app in VS2008 that will use some reports. My question: how to pass multiple integer value as one parameter and how to use it. I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841724/1447555) but it only work with first value in array (like single value parameter).
My csharp code:

```
rprt.SetParameterValue("idpoddet", new int[] { 5, 6, 7 });
```

my record selection formula:

```
{PODDET.id} in {?idpoddet}
```

Thanks for any reply or suggestion. Ondro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my mistake, i just disable page navigation buttons, so i didnt see there is more pages in my report :)